# Select2 Search not showing data in dropdown

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I am trying to populate a dropdown using Select2. but it is failing to get the data on front end while I can see the response in network.

Below is the source link of the code.

[enter link description here](https://www.codementor.io/tips/6543378221/a-slightly-slimmed-down-version-of-the-official-select2-ajax-example-on-how-to-have-an-ajax-powered-autocomplete-dropdown)

[image]

I have changed the URL with my own one.

[image]

but the data dropdown is not populating.

Here is complete code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <title>Quick Select2 Ajax-powered Autocomplete Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>The following autocomplete dropdown will list public GitHub repositories by querying the list with your search term.</p>
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" style="width: 300px;">
  <option value="464684" selected="selected">Search ...</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-data-example-ajax")
  .select2({
    ajax: {
      url: '/shajra_mmsj/index.php/home/get_parent',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, params) {

        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };

      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
      //console.log(markup)
      return markup; // let our custom formatter work
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: function(repo) {

      if (repo.loading) return repo.text;
      console.log(repo);
      return repo.full_name;
    },
    templateSelection: function(repo) {
//console.log(repo);
      return repo.full_name || repo.text;

    }
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume the URL ` url: '/shajra_mmsj/index.php/home/get_parent'` is incorrect - does this return JSON?

Comment: Yes its returning json.

Comment: Try using a full URL rather than relative